# How to remove Syntax error when doing mne_edf2fiff conversion

Tags: python, syntax-error, mne-python

I am new to MNE python, and wanted to convert the raw file provided to me in edf format to .fif format. However, I came across this problem. I was wondering if anyone could help me with resolving the issue. I am sharing the code below:

```
import matplotlib
import pathlib

import mne
import mne_bids

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

import numpy as py

import pyedflib

cd C:\Users\sxb2391\Downloads\Files

mne_edf2fiff --edf Try.edf --fif Recording_9_fil.fif
```

And this was the error I obtained:

> ```
> File "C:\Users\sxb2391\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12080>>/372198582.py", line 1
>    mne_edf2fiff --edf Try.edf --fif Recording_9_fil.fif
>                       ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Could someone help me with solving this error. That would be of great help.

Comment: `mne_edf2fiff --edf Try.edf --fif Recording_9_fil.fif` That is not python code.  Why is it in a python file?

Comment: `cd ...` is also not Python code. Why do you use it in Python? Python would need `os.chdir(r"C:\Users\sxb2391\Downloads\Files")`